# How do you connect a card reader?

Tags: installation, led, card-reader, case

I bought a Velocity micro case which came with a card reader built in. I installed a Gigabyte 880GA-UD3H and can't find a place to plug it in.

Do most motherboards have this option? Or did just get one that doesn't have it?

Also, the hard drive LED is not working. Is there a way to check if its the board or the case?

Answer (score 2):

Does it, by chance, plug in to a USB header?

[image: USB header]

Also, if your HDD light isn't working, make sure you read the manual and check the pinout for the LED header. Make sure the polarity isn't reversed (an LED is a diode; current can only flow in one direction through it).